# CSV2Table appearst to be caching results - how can I stop it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the CSV2Table plugin: [CSV2Table](http://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/)

The body of the html page is:

```
  <body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh();">
     <div id="CSVTable"></div>
  </body>
```

The TimedRefresh script is:

```
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
       function timedRefresh() {
         setInterval(function(){
         ref()},30000);
    </script>
```

The script to load the CSV into the DIV is:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

    function ref(){
        $('#CSVTable').CSVToTable('q.csv', { loadingImage: 'images/loading.gif', startLine: 0, tableClass:'table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover' }).bind("loadComplete",function() { 
        $('#CSVTable').find('TABLE').tablesorter().tableClass('table table-condensed');     
        
                    });
        </script>
```

The problem is, although the **ref** is called, CSV2Table appears to be caching the result - and not re-reading the CSV file (which is updated dynamically elsewhere).

Is there a way of stopping the caching from happening on CSV2Table?  I've tried googling, but can't find a cache setting for it!

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CSVToTable` uses `$.get`, so you can use [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set global ajax cache settings; e.g.

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

The above would prevent cache from being used in *all* subsequent AJAX requests, including those generated by `CSVToTable`. There are of course downsides to this approach, and the jQuery documentation itself advises against using `ajaxSetup`.

Another option would be to change the [source](https://code.google.com/p/jquerycsvtotable/source/browse/trunk/js/jquery.csvToTable.js#97) of the plugin, to use `$.ajax`, and to allow the passing of ajax options to the plugin, so that the plugin could be configured not to use cache. If you do go ahead and make such a change, you should of course submit it to the author so that it may be incorporated in the main branch, and you may download future updates without overwriting your own changes.